# Font Awesome weird colors in the background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome and it works perfect but in Chrome the icons show a strange "border". In IE and Firefox the problem does not appear.
It's also strange that the problem appears in chrome just if i have a zoom of 100% (so the normal view). If I zoom in a little bit, for example 110%, it's displayed totally correctly.

A Screenshot to describe the problem:

In Chrome
[image]
In IE, FF
[image]

Some code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-2 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 no-padding text-center social-github">
  <a href="">
    <i class="fa fa-github-square fa-2x"></i>
  </a>
</div>

.social-github > a {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}

.social-github > a:hover {
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .1s linear;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a demo?

Comment: Strange. In jsFiddle I can't reproduce the mistake http://jsfiddle.net/AmBdL/

Comment: @Michael the mistake is there .

Comment: Hmm strange. In jsFiddle I don't see the mistake. Just on the file I'm working on.

Comment: @Michael Try translating it by 1px in the z direction `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);`

Comment: It's definitely there in the jsFiddle. I see it.

http://jsfiddle.net/AmBdL/1/

Comment: Changed it to a navy background and exact size pixel units as suggested in an answer below, but it's *still* there.  http://jsfiddle.net/AmBdL/3/

Comment: Setting a pixel sizes on the body of 15px seems to yield the best results, but it's still not 100% gone. http://jsfiddle.net/AmBdL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a to Chrome and Windows related problem with rendering some fonts.

The easiest way to fix the problems seems to be to move the svg src in the CSS file in front of the WOFF but after the EOT to still maintain a propper display in IE but to force chrome to use SVG instead of the WOFF.

Here's for example the min version of font awesome with the changed order

`@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype');`

Better use this instead the code above:
With this little trick you can detect Chrome and prevent the download of the WOFF font:

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}`

Comment: glad you have found an answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

after setting width of the container to auto , the issue doesn't exist anymore , try using exact size units ( pixels .. etc ) instead of em.

Edit :

think the font size is controlled via using class `fa` , using the fa-1x also fixed it.

[image: 2x scale]

[image: 4x scale]

Comment: In my project I use bootstrap and I didn't set any width anywhere. Changing the size to fa-1x didn't solved it

Comment: <div class="social-github" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 32px"> you set width to 32px here , via inline css.

Comment: Just in the fiddle to "show" you the white icon so you find it. In my real project I don't have that border

Comment: @Michael trust me it is something related to the size ( font size ) , so the best temporary approach is to use large scale ( larger font size ) , and then controlling the actual size via container.

Comment: @Michael maybe you can try editing the css file , and try exact pixels , instead of using em units.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've also tried the MFG Labs Icon Set and it's exactly the same but again just in chrome. Even on their own website the icons look kinda pixelated. (Scroll Down http://mfglabs.github.io/mfglabs-iconset/)

Comment: @Michael ok im just trying to help , you may want to try www.fontello.com

Comment: Is it just me or does the fonts at fontello also look pixelated (size 30) in Chrome? Wtf

Comment: if you wanna do your custom font using svg it will allow you to do it , and yes it is kinda pixelated ( aliased edges )